# Applying functions to lists

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have a few expressions $f(\theta,x)$, $g(\theta,x)$, $h(\theta,x)$ in terms of two variables, an angle and a length. The angle goes from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ and the length from 200 to 1500. This is my domain.

I would like to first generate a list of the domain values of time and length, say, in 10m increments (200, 210, ..., 1490, 1500) and say 30 equally spaced values from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ for the angle.

I would like to then run $f$, $g$ and $h$ for *each datapoint* in the domain and generate a list of the output values of each function (the total "range"). I have been reading up on `Map` and `Thread` and that sort of thing but am struggling with generating the domain lists I want and with threading multiple variables. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach using `Table`. I find this more readable, although the one using `Outer` is more compact:

```
list = Table[
   Through[{f, g, h}[theta, x]],
   {theta, Subdivide[-Pi/2, Pi/2, 30]},
   {x, 200, 1500, 10}
 ]~Flatten~1
```

This will provide the list as triplets of $f,g,h$ values, as follows:

```
(* Out: {{f[-(π/2), 200], g[-(π/2), 200], h[-(π/2), 200]}, 
         {f[-(π/2), 210], g[-(π/2), 210], h[-(π/2), 210]}, 
         {f[-(π/2), 220], g[-(π/2), 220], h[-(π/2), 220]}, ... 
         {f[π/2, 1490], g[π/2, 1490], h[π/2, 1490]}, 
         {f[π/2, 1500], g[π/2, 1500], h[π/2, 1500]}} *)
```

If you would rather have lists of $f$ values, followed by a list of $g$ values, etc, you can `Transpose` the `list`:

```
Transpose@list

(* Out: {{f[-(π/2), 200], f[-(π/2), 210], f[-(π/2), 220], ..., f[π/2, 1490], f[π/2, 1500]},
         {g[-(π/2), 200], g[-(π/2), 210], ...}
         {...}}
*)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed answer - this solves my problem as well as giving me some insight into how Through works. A couple quick follow-ups - how do I use items from this list, i.e. 

- call list items in some other function, i.e. somefunction(fval,gval,hval) for each triplet?

- scan items from the list such as using NDSolve with initial conditions f[0] = fval, g[0] = gval, etc and run this for each triplet of values

Basically I really like the list of triplets, but not sure how to access these, i.e., telling a function which takes fval, gval...to scan across triplets
Thanks!

Comment: +1 for teaching me the function Subdivide, where I always did it manually.

Comment: @SarahThompson I am glad you found my answer helpful! From your description of the desired operation, it sound like you could `Apply` an appropriately constructed function to `list` at level 1, I.e. `f @@@ list`. Try that with an undefined `f` on a shorter list to see how it works. In your case, here is a made up usage example with `NDSolve`, where I use each triplet as a boundary condition: `NDSolve[{someEquations, f[0] == #1, g[0] == #2, h[0] == #3}, {f, g, h}, {x, someVal, someOtherVal}]& @@@ list`.

Answer (score 8):

```
Outer[f, Range[-15, 15] Pi/30, Range[200, 1500, 10]]
```

(Ok, that's actually 31 values for the angle, but that seems cleaner -- seems like you'd want zero to be one of the angles.)

For all three:

```
Outer[{f@##, g@##, h@##}&, Range[-15, 15] Pi/30, Range[200, 1500, 10]]
```